# Extracting multi-variable equation coeficcients with numpy.polyfit

Tags: python, numpy

this is one of those questions that's probably going to be totally obvious once answered, but for now I'm stuck.

I'm trying to re-create an equation from a result dataset and the four parameters that produced it.

The data is in a matrix with the last column being the result.

I saw that [numpy.polyfit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) allows multiple values for y, so I tried...

```
result=data[:,-1]
variables=data[:,0:-1]
factors=numpy.polyfit(result,variables,2)
```

Result comes out is:

```
[[-4.69652251e-01  8.09734523e-01  1.93673361e-02 -1.62700198e+00]
[ 1.42092582e+01 -7.06024402e+00 -9.94583683e-02  1.11882833e+01]
[ 7.44030682e+00  2.08161127e+01  2.65025708e-01  1.14229534e+01]]
```

I'm assuming the result coefficients are in the form

```
[[A^2,B^2,C^2,D^2]
 [A  ,B,  C,  D]
 [const,const,const,const]]
```

Which is a little puzzling, especially since if I apply the coefficients to the input data I don't seem to be getting anything even close to the result data.

First off, am I even right about the meaning of polyfit's results?

Second, why are there four constants, all different?  Am I supposed to add them together, or what?

Is this merely solving A vs result, then B vs result, etc, rather than combined multi-dimensional minimizing of the whole??  (And if so, how could I do that instead?)

Or am I just misguided what polyfit is doing in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

[Polyfit docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) tell us that

> Several data sets of sample points sharing the same x-coordinates can
>   be fitted at once by passing in a 2D-array that contains one dataset
>   per column.

Let us understand it.
Firstly, let us consider an example. Say we have 3 points on the plane and want to interpolate them by polynomial of degree 1. It means that we want to plot a line through given 3 points, and this line should have minimal squared distance to this point. 
Say, we have 3 points: `(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)`. Obviously, it is possible to find the line which is going through these points without any error, and this line is `y = x`. If we think of line in terms of `y = a * x + b`, then `a = 1, b = 0`.
[image: line y=x]

Good. Now let us start from giving this example to numpy polyfit:

```
X = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3])

a, b = np.polyfit(X, y, deg=1)

(a, b)
>>> (0.9999999999999997, 1.2083031466395714e-15)

a * 1000 + b
>>> 999.9999999999997
```

Nice. Now let us make the example with matrix instead of one vector of y. Docs told us that we are just having multiple lines with the same X coordinates. Let us check this. We take two sets of points: `(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)` with the line `y = x` that fits them and `(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6)`. The fitting line is `y = 2x` (check!).

[image: two lines]

We are transposing the second matrix because polyfit wants it.

```
X = np.array([1, 2, 3])
y = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]]).T
coeff = np.polyfit(X, y, deg=1)

coeff
>>> array([[1.00000000e+00, 2.00000000e+00],
       [1.20830315e-15, 2.41660629e-15]])
```

We see that we have a matrix with first row `(1, 2)` and second row `(0, 0)`. So the first column contains coefficients for the first line, and second one -- for the second line. Let us check:

```
a, b = coeff[:, 0]
a * 10 + b
>>> 9.999999999999998

a, b = coeff[:, 1]
a * 100 + b
>>> 199.99999999999994
```

So, you can pass multiple lines with the same X coordinates and get many fits simultaneously. It can be useful, for example, for transforming features for the whole bunch of data.